# The most efficient way to check for last element in XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

Basically I just want to check if the last element in the XML document I have is called

```
<element99>
```

or not, and if so, read its attributes. What would be the most efficient way to do so?

Is there a way not to load entire XML doc into memory?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Do you mean the last element at any depth?

Comment: @MichaelKay I mean the root

Comment: @KlausGütter no, I have not checked performance on various approaches

Comment: Please explain further what you mean by the "last element". If your document has `<doc><chap><sec1/></chap></doc>`, which one is the "last element"?

Answer (score 0):

You could evaluate the XPath expression `boolean(/*/*[last()]/self::element99)` which returns `true` if the last element contained in the root element is named `element99`. The expression `/*/*[last()]/self::element99/@*` returns the attributes of that element.

Answer (score 0):

In XPath you could do `(//*)[last()][self::element99]/@*`

or you could do `//element99[not(following::*)]/@*` - but this isn't quite the same thing - it will match an element99 that has children, and depending what you mean by "last", an element with children is never the last element in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Xml.XmlReader`.
In this approach the file will be read element-by-element and will not be loaded fully in the memory.

The following method checks if an `<element99>` exists, and if it is the last element.

```
bool CheckXml(string path)
{
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(path));

    if (!xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("element99"))
        return false;

    if (xmlReader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
        return false;

    xmlReader.Skip();

    while (!xmlReader.EOF)
    {
        if (xmlReader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement && xmlReader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Whitespace)
        {
            return false;
        }
        xmlReader.Read();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Since XmlReader only provides forward-only access, you have to

1. Read and store attributes before checking if the element is the last
   one.
2. Read the stream again and store the required attributes.